# Make Data Driven forms based on JSON with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

In AngularJS I am trying to make different editable forms from JSON data. I am getting JSON data from `$http` call.

Sample json data.

```
{ 
    {"NodeType": "User","NodeDetail":{"Name": "Sam", "Age":24,"Gender":"Male"} }, 
    {"NodeType": "User","NodeDetail":{"Name": "Dazy", "Age":22,"Gender":"Female"} },
    {"NodeType": "Occupation","NodeDetail":{"Type": "Contract","Traveling":"Yes","Benifits":"No", "Medical":"Annual"} },
    {"NodeType": "City","NodeDetail":{"Name": "London","Area":"1,572 sq-km","Elevation":"35 m","Population":"87.9 lakhs"} }
}
```

I am able to achieve in my HTML as below,

[image: HTML Example]

Based on the NodeType the form will have input, text area, radio button etc. As below image,

[image]

I think I can do by putting form in `ng-if` directive. But the problem is , there will be around 40-50 NodeTypes so having all form templates in ng-if will make the page very lengthy. I would prefer to have form template in a external .js file and load from there based on NodeType. Is it possible ? I please guide me what will be the best approach to achieve this. Pointer to any working demo/example will be great help.

Thanks & regards

Comment: Your JSON data is invalid

Comment: To be specific, your JSON data starts with an open curly-brace (`{`), implying an object, which means the next thing to appear should be a double-quoted property name. As you seem to desire a collection of objects, you should remove the opening `{` and closing `}` and replace them with `[` and `]` respectively.

Comment: @sand Your JSON data should be: `[{
 "NodeType": "User",
 "NodeDetail": {
  "Name": "Sam",
  "Age": 24,
  "Gender": "Male"
 }
}, {
 "NodeType": "User",
 "NodeDetail": {
  "Name": "Dazy",
  "Age": 22,
  "Gender": "Female"
 }
}, {
 "NodeType": "Occupation",
 "NodeDetail": {
  "Type": "Contract",
  "Traveling": "Yes",
  "Benifits": "No",
  "Medical": "Annual"
 }
}, {
 "NodeType": "City",
 "NodeDetail": {
  "Name": "London",
  "Area": "1,572 sq-km",
  "Elevation": "35 m",
  "Population": "87.9 lakhs"
 }
}]`.

Comment: @Danny. Yes i accept. Thanks a lot for correction.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` can cycle through keys and values. So once you select your object from that array, you can list the keys and values without any templates. Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
      "NodeType": "User",
      "NodeDetail": {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Age": 24,
        "Gender": "Male"
      }
    },
    {
      "NodeType": "User",
      "NodeDetail": {
        "Name": "Dazy",
        "Age": 22,
        "Gender": "Female"
      }
    },
    {
      "NodeType": "Occupation",
      "NodeDetail": {
        "Type": "Contract",
        "Traveling": "Yes",
        "Benifits": "No",
        "Medical": "Annual"
      }
    },
    {
      "NodeType": "City",
      "NodeDetail": {
        "Name": "London",
        "Area": "1,572 sq-km",
        "Elevation": "35 m",
        "Population": "87.9 lakhs"
      }
    }
  ]
  $scope.select = function(x) {
    $scope.selected = x;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="x in data">
    {{$index+1}}. <button ng-click="select(x)">{{x.NodeType}}</button>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in selected.NodeDetail">
    {{key}}: {{value}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aleksey , but we need to show data in forms which can be editable. Simple displaying the data is not the requirement.

Comment: @sand you would have to extend your json with something like `"type":"dropdown"` or `"type":"input"` and extent the form accordingly, otherwise you have no way of knowing how to display the data (that's where your ng-if would come in)

Comment: I can differentiate based on JSON keys, (Types, Traveling..) for dropdown and input, in "NodeDetail". But how to have the different form template which are data driven.